# Highcharts - Using a function to change the tooltip

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

So i'm using Highcharts (li3_highcharts helper to be specific) to display call times. I'm able to use a function to display "{point.y}" in the tooltip, but to make it more readable i need to be able to pass "{point.y}" to my secondsToTime() function which displays seconds as a readable time 00:00:00.

This prints the correct time in seconds:

```
'tooltip' => ['pointFormat' => '(function(){return "{point.y}";})()']
```

But when i try and pass "{point.y}" in the secondsToTime() function i just get 'NaN' because its not a number. I also added a parseInt() to the function incase its passed as a string, but nothing.

```
'tooltip' => ['pointFormat' => '(function(){return secondsToTime("{point.y}");})()']
```

Is there anywhere i can pass this function later that will allow it to work? or some work around?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is the issue, but it looks like you are passing a quoted string into your function rather than the integer value. Try:

```
'tooltip' => ['pointFormat' => '(function(){return secondsToTime({point.y});})()']
```

---

Sorry. Having looked again, I think I know what the problem is.

You are using 'pointFormat', which is supposed to take a string, not a function.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.pointFormat

If you want to call a function, there is a 'formatter' option

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter

I think you will need something like:

```
'tooltip' => ['formatter' => 'function(){return secondsToTime(point.y);}']
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I Tried this, and it just breaks the whole chart. Nothing is displayed...

Comment: Hmmm i tried that, but it just breaks again.  Using the 'formatter', 'tooltip' => ['formatter' => '(function(){return this.y;})()'] returns the seconds fine. But again when i try 'tooltip' => ['formatter' => '(function(){return secondsToTime(this.y);})()'] it just has no tooltip.

Comment: I don't think that you need the braces around the function.

Answer (score 0):

SteveP is correct I think except you need

```
'tooltip' => ['formatter' => 'function(){return secondsToTime(this.y);}']
```

instead of

```
'tooltip' => ['formatter' => '(function(){return secondsToTime(this.y);})()']
```